# Pointer needed to integrate using u-substitution

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have been at this problem for a bit too long now, using a calculator online I got an answer that is ~6 but my answers are always in the ~2 range, I would really appreciate if someone can point me to a fault in my reasoning.

Given the following,
$$\int_1^4 \left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^2dx$$

I couldn't find any convenient form for u, so I simply let u = $\frac1x$, which also means x = $\frac1u$

Consequently I get the form, $$\int_1^4 \left(u\cdot(1+\frac1u)\right)^2 dx$$

or  $$\int_1^\frac14 (u+1)^2 du$$

Next I see that this integral yields me, $$\left.\frac{(u+1)^3}{3}\right|_1^\frac14$$

From which I get $\frac{-387}{192}$

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: You changed from $dx$ to $du$ when you said "or". But those are not the same. You have swapped the limits correctly, but you can't leave the integrand unchanged.

Comment: do you really need a $u$-substitution? Try just expanding the bracket.

Comment: Note that you have an integrand of $\left(\frac{1}{x} +1\right)^2$  That can be expanded: $$\left(\frac 1{x^2} + \frac 2x+ 1\right)$$

Comment: If $x=\frac{1}{u}$, what is $\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: Your substitution is wrong, if you have $u = \frac{1}{x}$ then $du = \frac{-dx}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution you suggest is reasonable:  let $u = \frac{1}{x}$.  Then $\color{red}{x = \frac{1}{u}}$ and $\color{blue}{\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u}$.  To deal with the limits of integration, note that if $x=1$ then $u=1$, and if $x=4$ then $u=\frac{1}{4}$.  Hence, making the substitution, we obtain
\begin{align} \int_{1}^{4} \left( \frac{1+\color{red}{x}}{\color{red}{x}} \right)^2\, \color{blue}{\mathrm{d}x} 
&= \int_{1}^{1/4} \left( \frac{1+\color{red}{\frac{1}{u}}}{\color{red}{\frac{1}{u}}} \right)^2 \left(\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u} \right) \\
&= -\int_{1}^{1/4} (u+1)^2\cdot \frac{1}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_{1/4}^{1} \left( \frac{u+1}{u} \right)^2\,\mathrm{d}u, \end{align}
which is basically exactly what you started with!  So, while this change of variables seems reasonable, it really doesn't work out very well in the end.

Instead, I think that you are better off using a bit of algebra.  Expanding out the integrand, we have
$$ \int_{1}^{4} \left( \frac{1+x}{x} \right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{1}^{4} \frac{x^2 + 2x + 1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{1}^{4} 1 + \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \left[ x + 2\log|x| - \frac{1}{x} \right|_{x=1}^4,
$$
which is relatively straight-forward to evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for expanding on my approach, wasn't quite understanding what Jose and the commenters meant by dx = $\frac{-du}{u^2}$ since I do not treat the Leibniz's notation as a quotient, your answer helped clarify. I see it was once again the characteristic oversight on my part.

Comment: It is an easy mistake to make.  Just remember to keep track of the differential when you make a change of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x=\frac1u$, then $\mathrm dx=-\frac{\mathrm du}{u^2}$.

But you don't need to do a substution to compute this integral\begin{align}\int_1^4\left(\frac{1+x}x\right)^2\,\mathrm dx&=\int_1^4\frac1{x^2}+\frac2x+1\,\mathrm dx\\&=\left[-\frac1x+2\log|x|+x\right]_{x=1}^{x=4}\\&=\frac{15}4+\log(16)\\&\simeq6.5.\end{align}